# Unpacking for list indices?

Tags: python

I often find I have something like this:

```
cur = [0, 0] # the indices into array
matrix = [[1,1,1]]
```

where I do

```
matrix[cur[0]][cur[1]]
```

Is there any sort of unpacking syntax here? Like:

```
matrix[*cur]
```

Comment: No, there clearly can't be (because Python objects can be "indexed" with any object - after all, that's exactly how dictionaries work). If you repeat the logic, wrap it in a function or something.

Comment: Related: [Access nested dictionary items via a list of keys?](/q/14692690/4518341) The top answer's "get" function even happens to work for this case.

Comment: @Karl Why did you close it? That's about dicts, not lists.

Comment: Because, as you said, it's answered there - and all the same principles and reasoning apply. Would you have the same objection if the target were about tuples?

Comment: @Karl Now that I think about it, the main difference is OP's specifically asking about syntax. I've posted an answer specific to that, which wouldn't apply to dicts. (Though maybe `xarray` would work? I haven't used it very much myself. Anyway, I digress.) The other thing is that setting a new value in a dict is different from a list and the syntax OP's showing here also works on the LHS of an assignment, but maybe that's beside the point. Lastly, dicts also support `.get`, which lists don't.

Comment: You just need to pass a tuple

Comment: What do you mean @juanpa.arrivillaga ? I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you switch to NumPy and you're using Python 3.11+, then yes, [that works](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html).

```
import numpy as np

cur = [0, 0]
matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])

print(matrix[*cur])  # -> 1
```

Before Python 3.11, you can just convert to tuple:

```
print(matrix[tuple(cur)])  # -> 1
```

Based on the name `matrix`, NumPy might be a better solution in other ways too. For example you get [elementwise operations](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations).

---

**Note**: The Python 3.11 syntax change doesn't seem to be documented in the normal places ([what's new](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html) and [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions)). From a quick look, I only found it mentioned under [`typing.Unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Unpack): *"`*` couldn’t be used in certain places"*. It is covered [in PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#change-1-star-expressions-in-indexes) though, which introduced `typing.TypeVarTuple`.

Comment: matrix[*cur] is invalid syntax

Comment: @JoãoAreias Requires Python 3.11+. I didn't realize that. Just edited to mention it. Thanks for making me aware!

Comment: Oh, right, they changed that to support the new `typing.TypeVarTuple` thing. The syntax change doesn't seem to be in the "what's new in Python 3.11" page.

Comment: @user2357112 Huh! Yeah, it's not [in the grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions) either.

Comment: Does this only work with numpy @wjandrea?

Comment: @user129393192 It also works with NumPy-like librairies like Pandas, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I mean simply Python built-ins @wjandrea

Comment: @user129393192 No it does not. You've tried it yourself, right? and seen that it doesn't work?

Comment: I see. So the syntax I'm asking about DNE.

Comment: @user129393192 To be precise, the syntax does exist, and I'm demonstrating it here, but lists don't support this functionality (indexing with tuples).